# How to count the number of keys that exist in a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, hash, exists

I am working with an input file that contains tab delimitated sequences. Groups of sequences are separated by line breaks. The file looks like:

```
    TAGC     TAGC     TAGC     HELP
    TAGC     TAGC     TAGC 
    TAGC     HELP  
    TAGC
```

Here is the code I have:

```
    use strict; 
    use warnings; 

    open(INFILE, "<", "/path/to/infile.txt") or die $!; 

    my %hash = ( 
            TAGC => 'THIS_EXISTS', 
            GCTA => 'THIS_DOESNT_EXIST',
    ); 

    while (my $line = <INFILE>){ 
            chomp $line; 
            my $hash; 
            my @elements = split "\t", $line; 
            open my $out, '>', "/path/to/outfile.txt" or die $!; 
            foreach my $sequence(@elements){ 
                  if (exists $hash{$sequence}){ 
                         print $out ">$sequence\n$hash{$sequence}\n"; 
                   } 
                   else 
                   } 
                         $count++; 
                         print "Doesn't exist ", $count, "\n"; 
                   }
            } 
     }
```

How can I tell how many sequences exist before I print? I need to put that information into the name of the output file.

Ideally, I would have a variable that I could include in the name of the file. Unfortunately, I can't just take the scalar of @elements because there are some sequences that won't get printed out. When I try to push the keys that exist into an array and then print the scalar of that array, I still don't get the results I need. Here is what I tried (all variables that need to be global are):

```
  open my $out, '>', "/path/to/file.$number.txt" or die $!;    
  foreach my $sequence(@elements){ 
            if (exists $hash{$sequence}){ 
                  push(@Array, $hash{$sequence}, "\n"); 
                  my $number = @Array; 
                  print $out ">$sequence\n$hash{$sequence}\n"; 
             #....
```

Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $sequences = grep exists $hash{$_}, @elements;
open my $out, '>', "/path/to/outfile_containing_$sequences.txt" or die $!;
```

In list context, grep filters a list by a criterion; in scalar context, it returns a count of elements that met the criterion.

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to keep track of how many keys you are printing in a variable and once your loop finish, just rename the file with the number you calculated. Perl comes with a built-in function to do this. The code would be something like this:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

open(INFILE, "<", "/path/to/infile.txt") or die $!; 

my %hash = ( 
        TAGC => 'THIS_EXISTS', 
        GCTA => 'THIS_DOESNT_EXIST',
);
my $ammt;

while (my $line = <INFILE>){ 
        chomp $line; 
        my $hash; 
        my @elements = split "\t", $line; 
        open my $out, '>', "/path/to/outfile.txt" or die $!; 
        foreach my $sequence(@elements){ 
              if (exists $hash{$sequence}){ 
                     print $out ">$sequence\n$hash{$sequence}\n";
                     $ammt++;
               } 
               else 
               }
               print "Doesn't exist ", $count, "\n"; 
               }
        } 
}

rename "/path/to/outfile.txt", "/path/to/outfile${ammt}.txt" or die $!;
```

I removed the `$count` variable, since it's not declared in your code (strict would complain about that). [Here's](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) the official doc for `rename`. Since it returns True or False, you can check that it was successful or not.

By the way, be aware that:

```
push(@Array, $hash{$sequence}, "\n");
```

is storing two items (`$hash{$sequence}` and `\n`), so that count would be twice as it should be.